# Is the function unique?

Tags: real-analysis

Let a certain function $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} $ such that $f(nm) = f(n) f(m)$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log(f(n))}{\log n} = 1$.

**Answer:**

Evaluation on $m^n$, gives $$1=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\log (f(m^n))}{\log(m^n)}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n\log(f(m))}{n\log(m)}=\frac{\log(f(m))}{\log(m)}$$ So $m=f(m)$.

Is it possible to show the uniqueness of this function? If so, is it possible only to provide me a hint?

I found an idea, but I don't know if it is valid.

I suppose another function $g$ with the same properties as $f$ which $f \not= g$ for some $x \in \mathbb{N}$. So $\log (g(n)) = \log(n) + o(\log(n)) $ and $\log (f(n)) = \log(n) + o(\log(n)) $, then $\log (g(n)) = \log (f(n))$ $\implies$ $g(n) = f(n)$. Is it good or not?

Comment: I don't understand, haven't you found $f(m) = m$ for all $m$?

Comment: Is there exist another function different of $f$ with the same properties?

Comment: No. You have shown that if $f$ satisfies the condition, then $f(m) = m$ for all $m$. You not only shown the uniqueness, you find it out explicitly.

Comment: I doubt it highly.  The limits converge but they could be very different before that.

Comment: The limit argument is good provided e.g. $m \ge 2$ So that you get $m^n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty.$

Comment: f is define on N, not R.  Let f(n) = n/2 when n is even n otherwise.  That satisfies both conditions, don't they.  log(f(n)) = log(n) - {0, log 2} so the limit condition holds. and f(nm) = f(n)f(m) is obvious.  || (oops, no it isn't... darn!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first argument actually showed already that $f(m) =m$ for all $m$. Thus there are no other choices for $f$, $f$ has to be the identity function.

But concerning your argument, let me just point out that

- You are using the fact that if a sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges to $b$, then any subsequence $a_{n_k}$ converges to $b$. In your calculation you fixed a $m$ and let that subsequence be $k \mapsto m^k$.
- Thus, your argument only work for $m\neq 1$. Indeed, $k \mapsto 1^k$ does not give you a subsequence. But of course in this case it is even easier to verify that $f(1) = 1$ using $f(mn) = f(m)f(n)$.

Comment: I do not understand what you're trying to make me understand. You mean with the Bolzano-Weierstrass property, we have the uniqueness of f?

Comment: Nothing to do with Bolzano-Weierstrass. I am saying that if $\{a_n\}$ converges to $b$, then we also have $\{a_{m^n}\}$ converges to $b$ when $m\neq 1$. @J.G

Comment: How does that answer my question?

Comment: Indeed, this answer is not answering your question (after you wrote "I found an idea..."). This answer is telling you that you don't even need to do anything extra is check that $f$ is unique. @J.G

Comment: But why don't I need to check the uniqueness? I don't understand why my answer gives the uniqueness of f.

Comment: Because you know that $f(m) = m$ for all $m$. Now if $g$ satisfy the same condition, then the same checking gves $g(m)=m$ for all $m$. Thus $f(m) = g(m)$ for all $m$. Thus $f = g$. @J.G